# My Sql prepared statement insert avoid duplicate entry

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I want to insert some data into a table named USERLOGIN and be sure that no duplicate data will be inserted.
I wrote this code as my insert quesry in a java program:

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO USERLOGIN (" + "deleted," + "loginTime," + "userIpAddress," + "username)" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)"+ "WHERE "+"? NOT IN (SELECT loginTime FROM USERLOGIN )";
```

I want to check duplicate entries based on loginTime property.

However when I run my code I got this error: You have an error in your sql syntax

Could you please help me with this problem. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I suspect that there was more to the error message than that! Perhaps there is no syntax for INSERT... WHERE... !?!

Comment: Why not just mark the fields you do not want duplicates in the database as UNIQUE? Afterwards you can just catch a `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` whenever the code attempts to insert something that is not UNIQUE

Comment: I do not have access to database. it is supported by someone else. I am supposed to write a code that avoid duplication when an entry should be inserted

Answer (score 3):

**use this query :-**

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO USERLOGIN (deleted, loginTime, userIpAddress, username) " + "VALUES(?,?,?,?) " + "WHERE "+"? NOT IN (SELECT loginTime FROM USERLOGIN )";
```

Comment: could you please tell me how I should check for duplication in insert? I do not want to set a unique key in my table because I do not have access to database

Comment: ResultSet resultset = 
                statement.executeQuery("select * from tablename where col_name="+cn+"") ;
    int ct = 0;
   while(resultset.next())
      {
   ct++; 
      }
   if (ct > 0)
      {
   throw new SQLException("Duplicate info<br>Chemical Name " + cn );else
      {
   
   String qry1= "insert into tablename(deleted, loginTime, userIpAddress, username) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Comment: @Rana: You better add the code from your comment as part of your answer.